# Order of query execution in the SQL

Tags: database-theory

When a user writes a SQL query it needs to be scanned, parsed and validated. The question is in which order these three operations occurs in the process?

Scanning, Parsing, Validation or any other order to execute the query

Scanning refers to identifying the keywords, token, attribute names and relation names

Parsing refers to checking of the syntax whether it follows the syntax rules or not

Validation refers process of validating the names of relations and attributes.

Comment: Oracle's Concepts manual has a nice overview of their SQL Processing. Oracle's terms may not fit those of other systems or textbooks exactly. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/sql.html#GUID-1B95E60C-99C5-446D-9C6B-5D16EFE59ACF

Answer (score 1):

The process of scanning is the process of "reading" the text concretizing the SQL query. Parsing is instead the process of checking that it is syntactically correct (the elements of the language are in the correct order/occurrence). Since no check can be done on something that you do not see/perceive: scanning must precede parsing, or they must at least happen simultaneously in alternation (this is what happens in parsers design through flex & bison).

Most parsers carry out semantic correctness checks during the lexing phase while the input is read.

Since I do not know what you mean by "validation", I assume it is the process of checking that the query satisfies some correctness criterion. For instance, it does not access unexisting tables. This exact task can be carried out during the lexing phase but it is not compulsory to do so.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Most parsers carry out semantic correctness checks during the lexing phase while the input is read." - That's not true these days. In the vast majority of modern programming languages, type checking can't be performed during parsing. But it doesn't really matter if you interpret the question as asking about phase ordering rather than pass ordering.

Comment: @Pseudonym Quite often *some* semantic checks occur during parsing, although I agree that it isn't as common as it used to be.  I find that, if the grammar is truly context-free, it tends to be parsed first, then verified semantically.  But context-sensitive grammars are so tempting, that some languages choose to bring a little semantics into the parsing.  Off hand, the case that comes to mind is the processing of template in C++ and generics in C#.  C++ chose a context-sensitive approach to resolve an annoying ambiguity involving less-than.  C# chose to write a syntactic rule instead.